# Sum of every element with every other element in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving a problem in which I need to find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

> Abundant Numbers :A number n is called abundant if the sum of its
>   proper divisors is greater than n . And by mathematical analysis, it
>   can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as
>   the sum of two abundant numbers.

My approach for this problem is :
I have a list of abundant numbers and I am finding the sum of every number with every other number in the list. When I have all the new_numbers (sum of the numbers in the abundant numbers list) I will check the numbers which are not in the list and sum them.

But the part where I have to find sum of every number with others takes O(n^2) time . Is there a way to improve the complexity ?

Here's my code with sample example :

```
k=[1,2,3]    # actual list with 7427 numbers 
l=[]
for i in k:
    for j in k[k.index(i):]:
        if i+j<28123 and i+j not in l:
            l.append(i+j)
print l,len(l)

# result -->[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 5
```

Actually this is a [project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23)  question.

Comment: What are "abundant numbers"?

Comment: A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

Comment: Where does `28123` come from?

Comment: @ScottHunter Dude. Google it.

Comment: it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

Comment: `for j in k[k.index(i):]`. You've got an off by one there. You actually want `for j in k[k.index(i) + 1:]`. As it is, you're including the current element in the sum.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I also need the sum of same number

Comment: You might want to edit your question then. Right now you say you need every OTHER number.

Comment: @A.Kot Magic numbers in code should be documented, they shouldn't have to be Googled.

Comment: @pjs Its not an arbitrary number, its a mathematically proven upper bound. This problem is a math problem in addition to a python problem. If you don't understand both parts, then you probably can't offer a good solution.

Comment: I think (as long as k is a sorted list from lower to higher) if you `break` in the inner loop if i+j > 28123, you can reduce it to something like `O(nlog(n))`..... Maybe. Just a thought.

Comment: @A.Kot Irrelevant to what I said.  And note, I *didn't* say "arbitrary".

Comment: @pjs Yeah. Beware of math, magic numbers abound. Pun intended.

Comment: This, to me, seems like a P vs NP problem.... Guess I know what I'm going to be doing at lunch today.

Comment: Is there any way the problem can be recast as a convolution?  If so, you may be able to get an O(n log n) solution with a fast Fourier transform.

Comment: @pjs Have you seen the original problem I have updated a link to the problem . Here it is https://projecteuler.net/problem=23

Answer (score 1):

This is an O(n^2) problem. A lot of students come away from learning about complexity classes think that that is "bad", but once you convince yourself that there's no way around this being a O(n^2) problem, it's best to just accept it.  There are improvements that could be made to your code, but not to your algorithm.

Avoiding `index` will probably speed up your code, as will making `l` a set rather than a list.

```
k = abundant_list
s = set()
for i, x in enumerate(k): #i is index of x
    for j in k[i:]:
        l = x+j #no reason to do addition twice
        if l<28123:
            s.add(l) #sets discard duplicates automatically
```

Comment: Still looks O(n^2) to me.

Comment: Yes its still O(n^2)

Comment: @johnsmith It's going to be O(n^2).  Unless there's some clever property of abundant numbers that escapes me, you're going to have to actually sum each pair, and there's no way around that being O(n^2)

Comment: @ScottHunter fair enough.  I'll edit that into my answer

Answer (score 0):

As long as `k` is ordered, then you can safely break in the inner loop if i+j > 28123. I'm fuzzy on efficiency calculations, but i think that makes it O(nlogn).

```
k=[1,2,3]    # actual list with 7427 numbers 
l=[]
for i in k:
    for j in k[k.index(i):]:
        n = i+j
        if n<28123:
            if n not in l:
                l.append(i+j)
        else:
           break # this will save you the time of adding numbers you know are > 28123
print l,len(l)
```

Comment: But that's still a very valuable insight from a runtime/optimization perspective.  I'd probably put it in an `else` block instead of checking another conditional though

Comment: What if `i+j==28123`?  And you shouldn't need to test *both* <28123 and >28123.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I believe this one is O(n*log(n))</del>

```
MAGIC_NUMBER = 28123
k = abundant_numbers
l = [True] * MAGIC_NUMBER
final = []

for i in range(len(k)):
    for j in range(i, len(k)):
        if i + j > MAGIC_NUMBER:
            break
        l[i+j] = False

for index, value in enumerate(l):
    if value:
        final.append(index)
```

**Update:** As Patrick Haugh pointed out this is a O(n^2) problem and any solution will have to be -at best- O(n^2)

Comment: Side note: I have not test this code. So, I may have missed something.

Comment: How can this be `O(n*log(n))` ?

Comment: @johnsmith Sorry, I just tested it. It is not O(n*log(n)). For some reason I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used matrix to create a sum of abundant number pairs? Shouldn't that be faster then embedded for-loops

so for example:

```
ka = [[12 18 20]
      [12 18 20]
      [12 18 20]]

ka'= [[12 12 12]
      [18 18 18]
      [20 20 20]]

sum= [[24 30 32]
      [30 36 38]
      [32 38 40]]
```

The code would be something like this (using numpy):

```
k=[12, 18, 20] 
ka = np.tile(np.array(k),(len(k),1))
sums = ka + ka.transpose()
```